# How to prevent http redirects when using SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap-client, http-redirect

I am using standard SoapClient class to make requests to the payment server.

```php
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'follow_location' => 0,
    ],
]);

$options = [
    'uri' => 'urn:PaymentServer',
    'location' => 'http://localhost:8001/index.php',
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'trace' => true,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'connection_timeout' => 50,
];
$soapClient = new SoapClient(null, $options);

try {
    var_export($soapClient->GetPayment([]));
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();

    var_export($soapClient->__getLastResponse());
}
```

Script http://localhost:8001/index.php contains following code

```php
header('Location: http://example.com', true, 302);
exit;
```

I expect empty result, but the actual output contains HTML from example.com

I have tried `get_file_contents` function with the same stream context:

```php
var_export(file_get_contents('http://localhost:8001/index.php', false, $context));
```

And I have got empty string.

What SoapClient or stream context option should be set to prevent redirects?

Comment: Is the actual URL you request http or https? Maybe also try setting `max_redirects` option to 1 or 0 as well? https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: Thank you for advice! `max_redirects` option works. It was not entirely obvious.